# org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /brokers/ids

Tags: apache-kafka

zkserver start and kafka-server start

kafka create topic get error

```
kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic skproduce
```

`org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /brokers/ids`

Comment: Your broker did not register itself in Zookeeper. You should figure out why, check broker logs or something

Comment: thanks kafka in zk root node is /kafka I Create topic not The specified /kfka